# Image should be upload only that column which is clicked not in all

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image, flutter-gridview, flutter-column

I write a code where I have colums in Gridviw and each column has the property to upload the image.
The image will be uploaded on that column which is clicked but in my code when I click any column to upload an image it uploads in all columns.
so I want to upload an image on a particular column that I click.

so please help me to do this.

here is my code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/utils/widget_functions.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/custom/BorderIcon.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Relation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

class Photos extends StatefulWidget {
 var usrid;

 Photos({Key? key, @required this.usrid}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _Photos createState() => _Photos();
 }

 class _Photos extends State<Photos>{

 PickedFile? _imageFile;
 final String uploadUrl = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload';
 final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

 Future<String?> uploadImage(filepath, url) async {
 var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
 request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', filepath));
 var res = await request.send();
  return res.reasonPhrase;
}

Future<void> retriveLostData() async {
 final LostData response = await _picker.getLostData();
 if (response.isEmpty) {
  return;
}
if (response.file != null) {
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = response.file;
  });
} else {
  print('Retrieve error ${response.exception?.code}');
}
}

int counter = 0;
//List<Widget> _list = List<Widget>();
List<Widget> _list = <Widget> [];


@override
 void initState() {

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  Widget child = _newItem(i);
  _list.add(child);
 };
}

void on_Clicked() {
 Widget child = _newItem(counter);
  setState(
      () => _list.add(child),
 );
}

Widget _previewImage(i) {
 final _imageFile = this._imageFile;
 if (_imageFile != null) {
  return
    SizedBox(
      //width: 300,
      height: 100,
      child: Center(child:
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        child: Image.file(
          File(
            _imageFile.path,
          ),
          height: 80,
        )
      ),

      ),
    );

} else {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: _pickImage,
    child: SizedBox(
      //width: 300,
      height: 100,
      child: Center(child:
      Icon(
        Icons.image,
        color: Color(0xffcccccc),
        size: 60,
      ),

      ),
    ),
  );
}
}

Widget _newItem(int i) {
Key key = new Key('item_${i}');
Column child = Column(
    key: key,
    children: [
      Stack(
          children:  [
            Card(
              elevation: 0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffa1a1a1),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              ),
              child: _previewImage(i),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 9,
              right: 9,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => _removeItem(i),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  width: 20,
                  'assets/images/close.svg',
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]
      ),
    ]
);
counter++;
return child;
}

void _removeItem(int i) {
 print("====remove $i");

 print('===Removing $i');
setState(() => _list.removeAt(i));
}

void _pickImage() async {
 try {
  final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = pickedFile;
  });
} catch (e) {
  //print("Image picker error ${e!}");
  print("Image picker error");
}
}


@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
 final double padding = 25;
 final sidePadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding);
 var regID = widget.usrid;

 return Theme(
  data: ThemeData().copyWith(
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topRight,
                  end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  //colors: const [Color.fromRGBO(132,105,211,1), Color.fromRGBO(93,181,233,1), Color.fromRGBO(86,129,233,1)],
                  colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]
              ),
            ),
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    addVerticalSpace(10),
                    Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add Your Photos',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),),
                    ),
                    addVerticalSpace(30),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: sidePadding,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: GridView(
                                    //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                                      //childAspectRatio: 2/1,
                                      ),
                                      // children: List.generate(_list.length, (index) {
                                      //         //generating tiles with people from list
                                      //         return _newItem(index);
                                      // },
                                      // ),
                                    children: List.generate(_list.length + 1,
                                            (index) => index == _list.length ?
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () => on_Clicked(),
                                          child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Stack(
                                                    children: const [
                                                      Card(
                                                        elevation: 0,
                                                        color: Color(0xff8f9df2),
                                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                          side: BorderSide(
                                                            color: Color(0xff8f9df2),
                                                          ),
                                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                                                        ),
                                                        child: SizedBox(
                                                          //width: 300,
                                                          height: 100,
                                                          child: Center(child:
                                                          Icon(
                                                            Icons.add,
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            size: 80.0,
                                                          ),

                                                          ),
                                                        ),

                                                      )
                                                    ]
                                                ),
                                              ]
                                          ),
                                        ) :
                                        _newItem(index)),
                                  )
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
      persistentFooterButtons:[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 0, 18, 0),
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children:[
                ElevatedButton.icon(   // <-- ElevatedButton
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                    size: 15.0,
                    color:Colors.white,
                  ),
                  label: const Text(
                    'Back',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xffFDA766),
                      minimumSize: const Size(100, 49),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),)
                  ),
                ),
                Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(   // <-- ElevatedButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Relation(usrid:regID)),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                      size: 15.0,
                      color:Colors.white,
                    ),
                    label: const Text(
                      'Next',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Color(0xffFDA766),
                        minimumSize: const Size(100, 49),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ]

  ),
);
}


}
```

And here is my output:- [this is the output image before image upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D14P.png)

After image upload:- [and this image after upload where it uploads all two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp2Sg.png)

Please help me with how I solve this. I pass the argument while uploading but it doesn't work.
and it also has functionality of add and remove columns

I need this kind of output:- [this is the image of output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bdCx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `i` index inside `_previewImage(i)`. And when you pick the image, you should store them in a list, something like `List<PickedFile?> _images = [];` and inside of setState of `_pickImage` add picked image to that list.
Now inside of `_previewImage(i)` you would take only image at `i` index from `_images`.

You'll need to set initially null for every new item you add, so you don't get exception 'out of bounds'. So your initState, on_Clicked(), and _previewImage should look like:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      Widget child = _newItem(i);
      _list.add(child);
      _images.add(null);
    }
  }

  void on_Clicked() {
    Widget child = _newItem(counter);
    setState(
      () {
        _list.add(child);
        _images.add(null);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _previewImage(int i) {
    var imageFile;
    if(_images.isNotEmpty && i < _images.length){
       imageFile = _images[i];
    }
    else {
       imageFile = null;
    }
    if (imageFile != null) {
      return SizedBox(
        key: Key(i.toString()),
        //width: 300,
        height: 100,
        child: Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child: Image.file(
                File(
                  imageFile!.path ,
                ),
                height: 80,
              )),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () => _pickImage(i),
        child: SizedBox(
          //width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: Center(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.image,
              color: Color(0xffcccccc),
              size: 60,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _newItem(int i) {
    Key key = new Key('item_${i}');
    Column child = Column(key: key, children: [
      Stack(children: [
        Card(
          elevation: 0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xffa1a1a1),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
          ),
          child: _previewImage(i),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 9,
          right: 9,
          child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () => _removeItem(i), icon: Icon(Icons.close)),
        )
      ]),
    ]);
    counter++;
    return child;
  }

  void _removeItem(int i) {
    setState(() => _list.removeAt(i));
  }

  void _pickImage(int i) async {
    try {
      final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = pickedFile;
        _images[i] = _imageFile;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      //print("Image picker error ${e!}");
      print("Image picker error");
    }
  }
```

Also it would be good if you could refactor your code (for example instead of helper methods use widgets, [helper method vs widgets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo&list=PLjxrf2q8roU1Vm2a9EySYgeMo2DIhXUeK))

Comment: sory but it gives me error when i give `i` on `onTap: _pickImage()` like this `onTap: _pickImage(i)`  it says This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: Make sure you `_pickImage` is defined as `_pickImage(int i)` and inside onTap give it like this: `onTap: ( ) => _pickedImage( i )`. When you give it like `onTap: _pickImage()` it gets executed when build method is executed, not when tapped.

Comment: ok and how to get this image on that column right now i add  `child: Image.file( File( _imageFile.path,
    ),
   height: 80,
   )`     like this but it shows on all columns

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I edited your _previewImage there.

Comment: I added your code but now it didn't upload the image and show me the same columns after selecting the image from the folder.

Comment: I guess you didn't add pickedFile to the _images list inside of _pickImage method (as I stated in my answer) . I added _pickedImage method as well. Hope this solves your problem.